# how to do testing in react redux application using Jest enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

Login.test.js:-

```
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import renderer from "react-test-renderer";
import Login from "../Login";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
//import LoginReducer from "../../../redux/reducers/loginReducer";
import configureStore from "redux-mock-store";
const mockStore = configureStore([]);

describe("Login Component", () => {
  let store;
  let jsx;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({ login: { email: "", password: "" } });
    jsx = (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Login />
      </Provider>
    );
  });
  it("should render an email input tag", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(jsx);
    expect(wrapper.find("Field[type='email']").exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it("should render a password input tag", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(jsx);
    expect(wrapper.find('Field[type="password"]').exists()).toBe(true);
  });

  it("should render a submit button", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(jsx);
    expect(wrapper.find('button[type="submit"]').exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Appstore:-

/** combine reducers*/
let rootReducer = combineReducers({
register: RegisterReducer,
login: LoginReducer

```
Login.js:-
import { React, useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import "./common_style.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actionCreator from "../../redux/actions/userActionCreater";
import "../common/common_style.css";
import {
  Grid,
  Paper,
  Avatar,
  TextField,
  Button,
  Typography,
  Link,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import LockOutlinedIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import AccountCircle from "@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle";
import LockIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Lock";
import { Formik, Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";
//import { propTypes } from "react-bootstrap/esm/Image";
import InitializeReduxState from "./InitializeReduxState";

const paperStyle = {
  padding: 20,
  height: "70vh",
  width: 280,
  margin: "60px auto",
  marginTop: "110px",
};
const avatarStyle = { backgroundColor: "#1bbd7e" };
const btnstyle = { margin: "8px 0" };

const Login = (props) => {
  const initialValues = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
  };

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email("Please enter valid email").required("Required"),
    password: Yup.string("Enter your password")
      .required("Required")
      .min(4, "Password should be of minimum 4 characters length"),
  });

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    const payload = { email: values.email, password: values.password };
    props.login(payload);
  };

  let history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.isLoggedIn === true) {
      props.flashNotification({
        message: "Login Succeessful...",
        type: "success",
      });
      if (props.role === "admin") {
        history.push("/admin");
      } else if (props.role === "patient") {
        patientStatus();
      } else {
        history.push("/physician");
      }
    }
  }, []);

  const patientStatus = () => {
    if (props.currentUser.isActive) {
      history.push("/demographics");
    } else {
      history.push("/patientinactive");
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid>
        <Paper elevation={10} style={paperStyle}>
          <Grid align="center">
            <Avatar style={avatarStyle}>
              <LockOutlinedIcon />
            </Avatar>
            <br />
            <h4>Sign In</h4>
          </Grid>
          <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
          >
            {(props) => (
              <Form>
                <Field
                  as={TextField}
                  label="Email"
                  margin="normal"
                  type="text"
                  name="email"
                  // onChange={handleUserChange}
                  placeholder="Enter email"
                  fullWidth
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <AccountCircle />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  variant="standard"
                  helperText={<ErrorMessage name="email" />}
                />
                <Field
                  as={TextField}
                  label="password"
                  placeholder="Enter password"
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  // onChange={handleUserChange}
                  fullWidth
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <LockIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                  }}
                  helperText={<ErrorMessage name="password" />}
                />

                <Button
                  type="submit"
                  color="primary"
                  variant="contained"
                  style={btnstyle}
                  fullWidth
                >
                  Sign in
                </Button>
              </Form>
            )}
          </Formik>
          <Typography> Do you have an account ?</Typography>
          <a href="/registeruser">Sign Up</a>
          <p className="text text-danger fw-bold text-center">
            {props.globalmessage}!!!
          </p>
        </Paper>
      </Grid>
      <InitializeReduxState />
    </>
  );
};

const mapStatetoProps = (state) => {
  return {
    isLoggedIn: state.login.isLoggedIn,
    role: state.login.role,
    globalmessage: state.login.globalmessage,
    authToken: state.login.authToken,
    currentUser: state.login.loggedUserInfo,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    login: (user) => dispatch(actionCreator.Login(user)),
  };
};

let hof = connect(mapStatetoProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export default hof(Login);
```

Here I have tested my Login component with some simple test cases and I have also mock my store because my application is using Redux but it is giving me error like

expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
Expected: true
Received: false
I have a doubt that in beforeeach I have used the email and password. Is it correct? Is there is something that I have done wrong?

Comment: Can't help without seeing the code of `Login` component.

Comment: Now I have Added Login component

Comment: First I'd recommend to unit-test the React component by itself, not the redux-connected version of it. It is much simpler, no mocking of store etc. necessary. `connect()` is coming from an external library that we trust to be working after all. Second, the test you currently have is better off as a snapshot test, if you're simply asserting that an input is rendered. What would be a better subject to be tested is the redirect behavior in your component (in the useEffect). For this you need to mock the history api for example.

Comment: @  
timotgEven if I do component testing and  if I do not mock redux , then in that case it is giving me error like:
Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Login)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Login) in connect options.